# Members of a Intersection type

Tags: java, intersection, jls

This question is related to : [Lambda Intersection Type Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693369/compilation-error-lamba-target-type-intersection-type)

Please see the example:

```
public class X {
  Object o = (I & J) () -> {};
}
interface I {
   public void foo(); 
}
interface J {
   public void foo();
   public void bar(); 
}
```

I am trying to understand what are the members of the intersection type. Please see:
[JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/typesValues.html#108433).

It is not clear from the last statement:

> Then the intersection type has the same members as a class type (§8) with an empty body, direct superclass Ck and direct superinterfaces IT1 , ..., ITn, declared in the same package in which the intersection type appears.

It is not clear if the members of the intersection type are (union) all the members of all the superclass Ck and super interface ITk or it is really a intersection of all the members of supeclass Ck and superinterface ITk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that to be a union, i.e. think of the class being declared as `implements I,J` (or in the words of the spec: `class IntersectionType extends Ck implements IT1, IT2, ... ITn`).

Comment: you are correct. I experimented with a few examples.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693369/compilation-error-lamba-target-type-intersection-type.

I have written the answer at the above mentioned link.

Comment: Your intuition is understandable, but you've got the terminology backwards.  It does have the union of the _members_ of the two constituent types, but its called an intersection type because the set of values of type `A&B` are those that are in the intersection of `A` values and `B` values.

Answer (score 3):

The terms "intersection type" and "union type" in the type theory literature derive from a set-theoretic interpretation of types, where `String` describes the (infinite) set of all possible strings.

An intersection type is the intersection of two types; `Comparable & Serializable` consists of the intersection of `Comparable` and `Serializable`; its elements are those that are both Comparable and Serializable.

The *members* of an intersection type (e.g., methods) are going to look something like the union of the members of the types being intersected; this often confuses people into thinking they should be called union types instead.

Java does not have full-blown intersection types; they show up only in a few places, such as generic type bounds and lambda target types.